# Hangfire (v1.8.4) favicon not being displayed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, hangfire, hangfire-console

I'm using Hangfire version 1.8.4 to schedule some background processes, but when I fire the application it doesn't displays a default favicon.

This is how it's displayed right now:

[image]

Does someone know how to properly insert an icon onto Hangfire?

I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC 6.

I tried running the raw project (without any modifications) and the favicon is not displayed.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not the job of Hangfire. It's the job of asp core. Return a valid content when your server receives a get request for /favicon.ico. Maybe through a static file or a controller. If you search for _asp core favicon_, you should find enough possibilities.

Comment: Sorry Oliver, but I think it is indeed hangfire's job. This used to work, and it stopped after version 1.7.24 was released. In this version they added an empty favicon to stop showing the recurring favicon 404 message, but they did not implement a way for us to customize the icon. So, sorry, but this is for sure a Hangfire concern.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solve the problem by implementing the new feature and submitting a PR, which was accepted and merged.

The next version (1.8.5) will be released and contains a new property FavIconPath inside DashboardOptions.

https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/pull/2251

That's it.

Update:

Hangfire 1.8.5 was released, so now whoever wants to display a favicon simply needs to set the new FaviconPath property inside the DashboardOptions class.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4MD1.png)

Thank you all